# Difference of Opinion for Counts

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I made 2 small scripts in physics today, but now it is starting to bug me.

The first script, is 100% accurate: It is used to calculate the number of bill and coins required for the desired amount of cash.

First Script:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Change {

static Money[] coins;
static int[] counts;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    coins = new Money[11];
    counts = new int[11];
    coins[0] = new Money(100);
    coins[1] = new Money(50);
    coins[2] = new Money(20);
    coins[3] = new Money(10);
    coins[4] = new Money(5);
    coins[5] = new Money(2);
    coins[6] = new Money(1);
    coins[7] = new Money(25, true);
    coins[8] = new Money(10, true);
    coins[9] = new Money(5, true);
    coins[10] = new Money(1, true);
    System.out.println("Please type the change:\n");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String values = br.readLine();
    String[] split = values.split("\\.");
    System.out.println();
    int whole = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
    int small = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        while (whole >= coins[i].getValue()) {
            whole -= coins[i].getValue();
            counts[i]++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 7; i < 11; i++) {
        while (small >= coins[i].getValue()) {
            small -= coins[i].getValue();
            counts[i]++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (counts[i] > 0)
            System.out
                    .println((coins[i].getValue() == 100 ? "" : " ")
                            + (coins[i].isDecimal() ? (" 0."
                                    + (coins[i].getValue() < 10 ? "0" : "") + coins[i]
                                        .getValue()) + ": " + counts[i]
                                    : ((coins[i].getValue() <= 5 ? " " : "") + coins[i]
                                            .getValue())
                                            + ".00: "
                                            + counts[i]));

    }
}

public static class Money {

    int value;
    boolean decimal;

    Money(int value) {
        this(value, false);
    }

    Money(int value, boolean decimal) {
        this.value = value;
        this.decimal = decimal;
    }

    boolean isDecimal() {
        return decimal;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
}
```

Second script:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ChangeMax {


static Money[] coins;
static int[] nums = new int[2];
static int max = -2147483648;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    coins = new Money[11];
    coins[0] = new Money(100);
    coins[1] = new Money(50);
    coins[2] = new Money(20);
    coins[3] = new Money(10);
    coins[4] = new Money(5);
    coins[5] = new Money(2);
    coins[6] = new Money(1);
    coins[7] = new Money(25, true);
    coins[8] = new Money(10, true);
    coins[9] = new Money(5, true);
    coins[10] = new Money(1, true);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        int temp1 = i;
        for(int h = 1; h < 100; h++){
            int temp2 = h;
            int[] counts = new int[100];
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                while (temp1 >= coins[j].getValue()) {
                    temp1 -= coins[j].getValue();
                    counts[j]++;
                }
            }
            for (int k = 7; k < 11; k++) {
                while (temp2 >= coins[k].getValue()) {
                    temp2 -= coins[k].getValue();
                    counts[k]++;
                }
            }
            int sum = 0;
            for(int p : counts){
                sum += p;
            }
            if(sum > max){
                max = sum;
                nums[0] = i;
                nums[1] = h;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nMax coins and bills required at: $"+nums[0]+"."+(nums[1] > 9 ? nums[1] : "0" + nums[1]) + ": "+max+"\n");
}

public static class Money {

    int value;
    boolean decimal;

    Money(int value) {
        this(value, false);
    }

    Money(int value, boolean decimal) {
        this.value = value;
        this.decimal = decimal;
    }

    boolean isDecimal() {
        return decimal;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

}
```

The second script, does the same thing, but runs through all the values under $100.

The problem is, is that the second script says the max amount is 9, and achieved at $0.94.

The first, script, when you type something like $1.94, does not register that 10 is the new highest number, instead of 9.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: You mean the minimum number of coins required? The "max" would be 94.

Comment: Why do you do your CS homework during physics class? Do you do your physics labs during CS class?

Comment: My school does not offer computer science courses.

@user1071777 I want to be able to calculate the maximum amount of bill and coins required. Thanks for you answer, but it appears that there are a number of errors as the first program demonstrates. Just be adding 1 dollar or 3 dollars to the amount makes it 10 and 11 respectively. Why would this not be working correctly?

Comment: Are you sure you understand what maximum and minimum means?
For $0.05, the minimum is using one 5 cent coin, while the maximum is using five 1 cent coins.

Comment: Yes, I mean I want to get the maximum amount of coins required, while using the minimum possible. So it would use the biggest values first, then use the smaller ones to avoid just using all pennies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not planning on doing your homework I am not going to provide you with working code, but both scripts can be easily improved

1) Your money objects know whether a value of e.g. 10 represents 10 whole dollars, or 10 cents (or whatever you use in America, I would use Euro's and cents). But still you use an hard-coded index of your array where you switch from dollars to cents

2) The first script will fail when somebody uses a nice rounded number as input, without decimal part

3) If you would convert your input first to cents, and all your values in your coin array as well, your code will end up much cleaner and easier to understand. Something in the form of

```
int startAmount = ... ;//in cents
int remainder = startAmount;
int coinCounter = new int[coins.length];
for ( int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++ ){
  int currentCoin = coins[i];//in cents
  coinCointer[i] = 0;
  while( remainder >= currentCoin ){
    coinCointer[i] = coinCointer[i] + 1;
    remainder = remainder - currentCoin;
  }
}
//print out by looping over coinCounter, 
//and use the info contained in the Money class
```